# How I can delete a seperator without using str.replace in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DF:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  ... Unnamed: 23 Unnamed: 24 Unnamed: 25 Unnamed: 26 Unnamed: 27 Unnamed: 28 Unnamed: 29 Unnamed: 30 Unnamed: 31 Unnamed: 32
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN CMO & KPI   NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN FMS PSO Zywiec 1
1   NaN Year    2019    NaN NaN NaN Entity: NaN 1268    FMS - PSO Zywiec 1  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN FMS PSO Zywiec 1
2   NaN Month   12  NaN NaN NaN Month:  NaN 2019.12 December 2019   ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN FMS PSO Zywiec 1
3   NaN Period-1    2019.11 NaN NaN NaN Scope:  NaN SC_NONE None    ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN FMS PSO Zywiec 1
4   NaN Month-1 11  NaN NaN NaN Currency:   NaN LC  Local Currency  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN FMS PSO Zywiec 1
```

```
entity = df[df["Unnamed: 6"]=="Entity:"]["Unnamed: 9"].values[0]
```

I took the value of Entity in column unnamed 6 at column unnamed 9 and put it to another column.

```
df["Unnamed: 32"] = entity
```

the thing is i need to split this value so i can put each value o their own columns respectfully.

I used `entity = df[df["Unnamed: 6"]=="Entity:"]["Unnamed: 9"].values[0].replace("-","")` to remove "-" as a seperator and replaced it with white space.

then i split the value like this;

```
data_entity = entity.split(" ")
first_data = second_data = ""
if len(data_entity) > 1:
    first_data = data_entity[0].strip()
    second_data = data_entity[1].strip()
    third_data = data_entity[2].strip()
    fourth_data = data_entity[3].strip()
    fifth_data = data_entity[4].strip()
```

but with `.replace("-"," ")` I recieve an output like this;

```
['FMS', '', 'PSO', 'Zywiec', '1']

FMS

PSO
Zywiec
1
```

`.replace` didn't worked out for me because there is a place between FMS and PSO where i can't remove.

what should I use instead of `.replace` to remove that white space. I already tried to write the code `.replace("-","")` instead `.replace("-"," ")`. still there is a white space between them.

thanks for the helps.

Comment: what is your desired output when starting with: `"FMS - PSO Zywiec 1"`?

Comment: "FMS PSO Zywiec 1" with .replace I got ['FMS', '', 'PSO', 'Zywiec', '1']. I want to get rid of <">

Comment: no images please. post data as a code or text

Comment: `"FMS - PSO Zywiec 1".replace('-', '').split()`

Comment: Couldn't display data as a code or plein text. I editted but it is complicated to understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When just using `.replace('-', '')` the output is:

```
'FMS  PSO Zywiec 1'
```

As there are two spaces in between `FMS` and `PSO`, the output for using `.split(' ')` contains an empty string. You can just use `.split()` to solve this problem. This will give you just the words from the string (no empty strings).

```
>>> "FMS - PSO Zywiec 1".replace('-', '').split()
['FMS', 'PSO', 'Zywiec', '1']
```